# Quiz Mark Convert into percentage

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, python-3.x, button

Is there any other way? In the result box, I want to convert my variable total into a percentage. I tried to make the total variable into a percentage, but it's defined as a global.This is my code. Please look at the markbox. I tried to divide the str(total)/2*100 but can't.

```
import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox

    total = 0
    EasyBox1 = Tkinter.Tk()
    EasyBox1.geometry("250x200")
    EasyBox1.title("Quesion 1")

    EasyBox2 = Tkinter.Tk()
    EasyBox2.geometry("250x200")
    EasyBox2.title("Quesion 2")

    ResultBox = Tkinter.Tk()
    ResultBox.geometry("320x260")
    ResultBox.title("Results")

    def next1():
        global total
        if not answr1.get(): tkMessageBox.showerror('no answer')
        elif int(answr1.get()) == 8: total += 1
        print "total after 1:",total
        EasyBox1.withdraw()
        EasyBox2.deiconify()

    def mark():
        global total
        if not answr2.get(): tkMessageBox.showerror('no answer')
        elif answr2.get() in ["B", "b"]: total += 1
        print "total after 2:", total
        EasyBox2.withdraw()
        LabelName5 = Tkinter.Label(ResultBox, text="Marks : " + (str(total))/2*100, font=("Impact",20))
        LabelName5.grid(row=2,column=0)
        ResultBox.deiconify()

    # window 2
    Tkinter.Label (EasyBox1, text="answer:").pack()
    answr1 = Tkinter.Entry (EasyBox1)
    answr1.pack()
    LabelName2 = Tkinter.Label (EasyBox1, text="State the number of edges in a cube")
    LabelName2.grid(row=1,column=0)
    LabelName2.pack()

    # window 2
    Tkinter.Label (EasyBox2, text="answer:").pack()
    answr2 = Tkinter.Entry (EasyBox2)
    answr2.pack()
    LabelName2 = Tkinter.Label (EasyBox2, text="What is the place value of the digit 4 in 76421?")
    LabelName2.grid(row=1,column=0)
    LabelName2.pack()
    LabelName2 = Tkinter.Label (EasyBox2, text="A.Thousands B.Hundreds C.Ones D.Tens")
    LabelName2.grid(row=1,column=0)
    LabelName2.pack()

    # hide windows
    EasyBox2.withdraw()
    ResultBox.withdraw()

    Tkinter.Button(EasyBox1, text="Next", command=next1).pack()
    Tkinter.Button(EasyBox2, text="result", command=mark).pack()
    EasyBox1.mainloop()
```

Comment: @WoLy i need your help. Can you help me?

Comment: @adrianus do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to convert a number into a string then divide it by 100. You may modify a variable no matter if it's a local or global variable.

I think instead you should use a format string. The %% prints the % sign. while the %.2f converts the float (f) into a string with 2 decimal places (.2).

```
text="Marks : %.2f %%" % (total/2*100.0)
```

Comment: still not working. the error is cant sign to function call

Comment: the error is cant sign to function call. I already change to text code you given to me

Comment: I mean, can you provide the output that states exactly the line with the error?  I've never heard of this error before.

Comment: i change this code LabelName5 = Tkinter.Label(ResultBox, text="Marks : " + (str(total))/2*100, font=("Impact",20)) to the code youve given to me.

Comment: I understand this. There is an output that states the error and the line that which the error occurs on. I would like to see the output that describes why the code is not working. The description of the error is vague and we need to see exactly what the problem is.

Comment: this is my code that not works  LabelName5 = Tkinter.Label(ResultBox, text="Marks : %.2f %%"), font=("Impact",20)

Comment: That's not an error log. I'm looking for something like: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "your file name.py", line 1, in <module>
    import blargh
ImportError: No module named 'blargh'

Comment: ouh sorry. the error log is cant sign to function call(question mini it.py,line 32). is this what you mean?

Comment: You didn't copy the code correctly. It should be LabelName5 = Tkinter.Label(ResultBox, text="Marks : %.2f %%" % (total / 2*100.0), font=("Impact",20)). The line of code is saying that it can't deiconify the the resultbox. It's probably looking for a format string but never received one and then complaining about it.

Comment: sorry my silly mistake. At first i try copy it but it doesnt work. But now the problem is although i get just one correct answer, but the percentage still 100.00%

Comment: I think that's another issue. You don't seem to increment for the number of questions asked and for how many were correctly answered. You'll need to do this and replace total in the format string with the result of dividing how many questions were correctly answered over the total number of questions asked.

Comment: can you give an example?sorry for taking your time

Comment: do you have any idea to solve my problem. I really need your help

Comment: Could it be that the message says "assign" and not "sign"?

Comment: @Matthias  what do you mean?can you give example?

Comment: I think the message you got was `"SyntaxError: can't assign to function call"`. You said it was `"can't sign to function call"` and that makes no sense. Please don't just write down what you think you've read on the screnn, use copy&paste instead.

Comment: @Matthias i got no error just the problem is the way of mark() function is wrong cause the tkmassagebox should give out different output

Comment: I  think you should open a different question to solve the second problem.